# Visual Studio 2010 - "Hover over" no longer working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE, which hopefully someone can help with.  Basically I've lost all of the tooltips I had previously:

- If there is an error or warning in the code and I hover over it then nothing happens, i.e. no tooltip appears telling me what the error/warning is.
- If I hover over a variable then nothing happens
- If I debug and break the code and hover over the line where it is stopped I am unable to get the value of any of my variables.

I've tried pressing CTRL+K,I and also using the toolbar item, but that hasn't made any difference.  I also can't find anything in the options which looks like what I want.

This happens on all of my projects (all C# .NET 3.5/4) - I am presuming I've turned something off but no idea what it is or how to fix it!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the dev environment and restarting?

Comment: I'll give it a go and get back to you....

Comment: Have you installed any extensions recently? Maybe one of them breaks something.

Comment: Might help: http://everymanprogrammer.com/index.php/how-to-reset-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Well a restart seems to have fixed it - no idea why, but I guess "turning it off and on again" really does work :)  Thanks for everyones help